# How do I trigger both of these?

Tags: php, mysql

Very new to PHP. Please forgive me if this question is ridiculous. Anyway, I have some PHP which sends data off to a database. Here is some of it:

```
else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$pass')";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $username (
day VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
P1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P1_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P2_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P3 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P3_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P4_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P5 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P5_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P6 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P6_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "okay";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
    }
```

When I run this, I realize only the second `$sql=` will be carried out, because I define `$sql` twice in the same instance. How can I make it so both of these events are triggered in one go? Thanks!

Edit: Full code

```
<?php
echo error_reporting(E_ALL);
$username = strval($_GET['enteredUserName']);
$pass = strval($_GET['enteredPassword']);
$firstname = strval($_GET['enteredFirstName']);
$lastname = strval($_GET['enteredLastName']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)  {
    echo "pop";
} else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$pass') ";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $username (
day VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
P1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P1_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P2_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P3 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P3_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P4_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P5 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P5_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P6 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P6_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "okay";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
    }
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, $sql1); mysqli_query($con, $sql2)`

Comment: U used same variable for two different queries. use different variable

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand where this would be inserted. Ill add my full code to the question @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*use `$sql1` and `$sql2` two different variables for your two queries and then*

***Either (both at a time):-***

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql1) && mysqli_query($con, $sql2)){
   echo "Ok";
}else{
   echo "Error";
}
```

***Or one-by-one:-***

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql2)){
        echo "OK";
     }else{
        echo "error";
     }
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

***Or You need to check `mysqli_multi_query()`:-***

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: `if (mysqli_query($con, $sql) && mysqli_query($con, $sql2))`?

Comment: @u_mulder  yes. I am editing that one. But thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Caspar   glad to help you  :):):)

Answer (score 1):

Like u_mulder said in comments, you can just do it this way, as mysqli_error [returns empty string if there is no error occured](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

```
$sql1 = 'first query';
$sql2 = 'second query';
mysqli_query($h, $sql1);
mysqli_query($h, $sql2);
$errorOccured = false;
if (strlen(mysqli_error($h)) > 1) {
    $errorOccured = true;
}
```

Have a look at [mysqli_error in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Or, as have been pointed out, just do two mysqli_queries and check their return values.
Or, if you need to execute queries as whole, you can also use things called "transactions", have a look at one of the comments examples. Taken from [mysqli_rollback in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php):

```
    $all_query_ok=true; // our control variable 

//we make 4 inserts, the last one generates an error 
//if at least one query returns an error we change our control variable 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (100)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (200)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (300)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; 
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO myCity (id) VALUES (100)") ? null : $all_query_ok=false; //duplicated PRIMARY KEY VALUE 

//now let's test our control variable
// This is shorthand if else statement
// ($statement) ? If true : if false;
$all_query_ok ? $mysqli->commit() : $mysqli->rollback(); 

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use different variables for different query

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$pass')";

$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE $username (
day VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
P1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P1_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P2_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P3 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P3_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P4_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P5 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P5_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
P6 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
P6_WORK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1) && mysqli_query($con, $sql2)) {
    echo "okay";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: you welcome :) If my answer is correct click to accept the answer